# Django Formsets: Member forms clean method not working?

Tags: python, django, forms

I created a model form which has custom `clean()` method. But this `clean()` method is not working anymore since I created a formset out of that modelform as it is unable to find the data in the `QueryDict`. So what to do now to make it work(find the data related to that form in the formset QueryDict)?

This is the member form:

```
class option_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = option
        exclude = ('warval','user')

    def clean_value(self):
        self.data = self.data.copy()
        print(self.data)
        if self.data['value']=='lol@lol.co':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This can't be your email address")

        return self.data['value']
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: "Key 'value' not found in <QueryDict: {u'form-1-value': [u''], u'form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], u'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u''], u'form-0-id': [u'1'], u'form-1-id': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'e645de635fe47559ac540eb32ea4d08d'], u'form-0-value': [u'lol@lol.co']}>"
```

Comment: Some sample code can helps to isolate problem.

Comment: Are you calling super's clean method before you access attributes in your clean? Something like _super(MyModelForm, self).clean()_

Comment: Nope,I'm not calling any super's clean method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `clean_value` method, you should fetch the value from `self.cleaned_data`, not `self.data`. See the docs on [cleaning a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for an example.

`self.data` is the raw POST or GET data that you initialised the form with. It doesn't contain a key named `value`, because the keys are [prefixed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) with values like `form-0-`.

Try changing your clean method to the following:

```
def clean_value(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data['value']
    if value == 'lol@lol.co':
        raise forms.ValidationError("This can't be your email address")
    return value
```